# Bind an object with the same object in an array

Tags: angularjs

I use angular 1.3.x.

I have one big form. In a first step, I can edit the person name in the form so I have an object person bind to the scope and an input with ng-model:

```
$scope.person = { name: 'John' };
```

Later, in the same form, I have a list of contacts (which is person like above) and in this list I can have again the SAME person as previous.

I want that the person can be edited in the first part or last part of the form: if I change the name in the first input, it must be changed in the second input and vice versa.

I tries to do something like that:

```
$scope.contacts = [];
$scope.contacts.push(person);
```

The second form is correctly filled but if I change the name in the first input field, the second input field isn't updated.

Any idea how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the only way you are loading data into `$scope.contacts`?  If so this should work since you are sharing the same object reference.

Comment: $scope.contacts is at first loaded with an http request with restangular and I add the person after the user click on a button.

Comment: Checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11985/
Hope it helps!

Comment: Isn't the fiddle working as you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects are not properly updating because they are distinct objects with separate references.  One work-around I found is to make sure to bind to the exact same object after filling the array's data.

After you populate the `$scope.contacts`, you should set your `$scope.person` to the proper object contained in that array.  I use this approach to loop through the array and set the matching objects equal to each other.  Then the bindings update properly.

```
.success(function (contacts) {
    $scope.contacts = contacts;

    //loop through and find first match, set them equal
    var foundMatch = $scope.contacts.some(function(contact) {
        if (areSame(contact, $scope.person)) { //you define areSame() logic
            $scope.person = contact;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Since your `person` can be set after a button press, you will have to use the loop-searching logic after the button press as well.

Comment: Yes when you asked from where contacts come, I understand my mistake. Thanks for your help.